# Single sign on using nodejs and jwt

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, jwt

Can we create a single sign on with multiple NodeJs applications? Main application is using JWT authentication. I want to use same user authentication to work in other applications without having complete user profile information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Include whatever information is useful for you when signing your jwt token. Send this token to the other applications, verify it and you can authenticate the user.